# Como puedo pedir dos fechas en JSF con PrimeFaces y Java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Quiero recibir dos fechas, hasta el momento tengo esto:

***En el xhtml:***

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="5" cellpadding="5" >
        <p:outputLabel for="fechaInicio" value="Fecha Inicial:" />
        <p:calendar id="fechaInicio" value="#{fechaV.fechainicio}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="fechaFin" value="Fecha Final:" />
        <p:calendar id="fechaFin" value="#{fechaV.fechaFin}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Consultar" id="conFechas" actionListener="#{fechaV.consulFechas}" update="demForm" icon="fa-th-list" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

> En java tengo esto:

```
public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        setVfech(obtfecha.getVfech(fechaInicio));
        setVfech(obtfecha.getVfech(fechaFin));

    }
```

Lo que quiero es, que al momento de darle en consultar, poder jalar las dos fechas. Bueno el rango de fechas y no entiendo como queda el evento :(

Comment: Quieres validar ese rango de fechas?

Comment: sip, quiero hacer la validación de las fechas :(

Comment: Que hace este mètodo ? consulFechas() ?

Comment: una consulta de ese rango de fechas, bueno eso es lo que quiero que haga pero no se bien como mandarlas D:

Comment: edita tu pregunta y agrega ese mètodo, asì se podrà reproducir el error que se te presenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que veo quieres validar un rango de fechas, te dejo un ejemplo para validar Fecha inicial y una Fecha final donde no sean mayor a 30 dias y no sean mayor a la fecha de hoy.

Primero que nada en el Managed Bean definir las propiedades a usar:

```
    private boolean fechaInicialFinalMayoraHoy;
    private boolean fechaInicialyFinMayor30Dias;
    public static final int NEGATIVO_TREINTA = -30;

    private Date fechaInicio;
    private Date fechaFinal;
```

Agregar sus respectivos métodos accesores. Si miras, tenemos dos  propiedades de tipo **Date**, en estos se almacenara la **fecha inicial y fin** que deseamos comparar.

Ahora agregamos el método que se encargará de validar la fecha inicial y la fecha fin:

```
 public void validarFechas() throws Exception {
        fechaInicialFinalMayoraHoy = false;
        fechaInicialyFinMayor30Dias = false;
        if (this.fechaInicio != null && this.fechaFinal != null) {
            if (isMayorFechaHoy(this.fechaInicio)
                    || isMayorFechaHoy(this.fechaFinal)) {
                fechaInicialFinalMayoraHoy = true;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Fecha Inicio o Fecha Fin es mayor a la fecha de hoy"));
            }
            if (isMayor30Dias(this.fechaInicio, this.fechaFinal)) {
                fechaInicialyFinMayor30Dias = true;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Fecha es mayor a 30 dias."));
            }
        }
    }
```

Primeramente validamos que los campos de tipo fecha sean != de null,  posteriormente se valida que la fecha no sea mayor a la fecha de hoy (sysdate), la siiguiente validacion será que los rangos de fechas no sean mayores a 30 días.

Agregamos el código del método booleano que se encarga de verificar que la fecha ingresada no sea mayor a la fecha de hoy.

```
 /**
     * Descripci&oacute;n de la regla: Si la fecha inicial o la fecha final es
     * mayor a la fecha acutal. la validaci&oacute termina como incorrecta
     *
     * @param fecha La fecha inicial de consulta o la fecha final de consulta .
     * @throws Exception Si las fechas violan la regla de negocio.
     */
    public Boolean isMayorFechaHoy(Date fecha) throws Exception {
        Date hoy = new Date();
        Boolean resultado = false;

        if (fecha != null && fecha.after(hoy)) {
            resultado = true;
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

Y para finalizar, método que valida el rango de las dos fechas ingresadas:

```
/**
     * Descripci&oacute;n de la regla: Si la fecha final es mayor a 30
     * d&iacute;as de la fecha inicial la validaci&oacute termina como
     * incorrecta
     *
     * @param fechaInicial La fecha inicial de consulta.
     * @param fechaFinal final de consulta.
     * @throws Exception Si las fechas violan la regla de negocio.
     */
    public Boolean isMayor30Dias(Date fechaInicial, Date fechaFinal) throws Exception {
        Date fhFinal = fechaFinal;
        Boolean resultado = false;
        if (fechaInicial != null && fhFinal != null) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(fhFinal);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, NEGATIVO_TREINTA);
            fhFinal = c.getTime();
            if (fechaInicial.getTime() < fhFinal.getTime()) {
                resultado = true;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Con esto terminamos de lado del back end, ahora veamos la vista, tendremos nuestro archivo XHTML muy sencillo  y queda así:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Validar rango de fechas</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>

            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="1" cellpadding="1">
                    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="fechaInicio" value="Fecha Inicio" />
                     <p:calendar id="fechaInicio" value="#{validarFechas.fechaInicio}" showOn="button" />    

                     <p:outputLabel for="fechaFin" value="Fecha Inicio" />
                     <p:calendar id="fechaFin" value="#{validarFechas.fechaFinal}" showOn="button" />    

                    <p:commandButton value="Validar" actionListener="#{validarFechas.validarFechas}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

Ahora a hacer deploy. Una vez hay deploy OK, probaremos ingresando un rango de fechas que sea mayor a 30 días:

[image: Rango]

Al presionar el botón validar, nos saltara el error:

[image: error1]

Ahora ingresemos una fecha mayor al día de hoy:

[image: error3]

Al validar vemos el error:
[image: error4]

```
Versión Prime faces usada:
 Prime Faces 5.0
 Glass Fish server 4.1.1 
 JSF:2.2
```

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si te sirve puedes poner esta respuesta como Aceptada y les pueda servir  a mas personas. Saludos